# Can't add an event to a button

Tags: javascript, windows-8, dom-events, microsoft-metro

I am working on this Windows 8 test application and I'm using the grid app template. In the itemDetail.html I have the following HTML code (I removed all the other code in that div and added this button, the rest of the html is untouched):

```
<div class="item-info">
     <button id="menuLink">Get me the menu</button>
</div>
```

I added the following JS code in the ready member of the Pages.define function in itemDetail.js:

```
var menuButton = document.getElementById("menuLink");
menuButton.setAttribute("onclick", "menuButtonClickHandler()");
```

The `menuButtonClickHandler()` function is declared right after the Pages.define function with the following code:

```
function menuButtonClickHandler() {
    var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Here's your menu");
    }
```

When I click the button I get the following exception:

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'menuButtonClickHandler' is undefined

Where am I suppose to 'define' this function? the template is using every other code from the JS file where that function already is so the function should be available to it.

Also for some strange reason I can't even add the event if I use `addEventListener`:

```
menuButton.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler, false);
```

Comment: I'v haven't done any windows 8 app programing yet, so I can't say for sure. The `setAttribute` way looks bad, I wouldn't add an event like that. addEventListener is usually the way to go in JS, your's looks fine except you have `buttonClickHandler` instead of `menuButtonClickHandler` which might be a typo or could be your problem

Comment: I typed that out while writing this post because that didn't have any effect and I moved on to the setAttribute function. I'll correct the mistake now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you try to add event listener is quite dirty and not working obviously. Try something like this:

```
var menuButton = document.getElementById("menuLink");
menuButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
     //do something
}, false);
```